# APNS to open a certain part of an application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I've just implemented a commenting feature in my app. Ideally when someone leaves a comment, I'd like all notified people be able to swipe the push notification and open the app on that post.

Comment: So,... what have you tried, what has failed, how has it failed, and what specifically is your question about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to open the concerned page directly. There are many ways to go about this, and it depends on how your app is laid out.

If you want to open an inner page upon app launch, you can programmatically trigger the segues that the user would otherwise need to make manually. (this ensures the back/home buttons work as opposed to loading the desired page directly).
Here's an excerpt from one of my own code, your use case may not be the same, but this is all i can do unless you give us more details.

```
- (BOOL) navigateToRespectiveSectionforPushNot:(NSDictionary*)pushNot
{
 id rootVC = self.window.rootViewController;

 NSLog(@"ROOT CLASS : %@", [rootVC class]);
 if ([rootVC isKindOfClass:[SWRevealViewController class]])
 {
   NSLog(@"Root Class looking good... mission Navigate!!");
   SWRevealViewController *homeVC = (SWRevealViewController*) rootVC;

    NSString *category = [[pushNot objectForKey:pushPayloadKeyaps] objectForKey:pushPayloadKeyCategory];
    NSString *subCat = [[pushNot objectForKey:pushPayloadKeyaps] objectForKey:pushPayloadKeySubCategory];
    NSLog(@"category : %@ , subcat : %@",category,subCat);
    //The code for the page to which i'm supposed to navigate to is contained in the push notification payload

    if ([category isEqualToString:pushCategoryItemChat])
    {
        [homeVC.rearViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"chatPush" sender:nil];
        UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController*)homeVC.frontViewController;
        NSLog(@"FrontView Class : %@",[nc.viewControllers[0] class]);
        UITableViewController *tvc = (UITableViewController*)nc.viewControllers[0];
        NSDictionary *send = @{chatPushTargetUserId:subCat,chatPushTargetUserName:@"",chatPushTargetUserImage:@""};
        [tvc performSegueWithIdentifier:@"seguePushDemoVC" sender:send];
        return YES;
    }
    //communityPush historyPush
    else if ([category isEqualToString:pushCategoryItemCommunity])
    {
        if ([subCat isEqualToString:pushSubCatItemNewRequest])
        {
            [homeVC.rearViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"communityPush" sender:nil];
            return YES;
        }
        else if ([subCat isEqualToString:pushSubCatItemAccepted])
        {
            [homeVC.rearViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"communityPush" sender:nil];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    else if ([category isEqualToString:pushCategoryItemHistory])
    {
        [homeVC.rearViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"historyPush" sender:nil];
        return YES;
    }
 }
 else
 {
    UIAlertView *whoa = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WHOA!!" message:@" That wasn't supposed to happen. You are not even logged in. Call 911..." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"mmKay.." otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [whoa show];
 }
 return NO;
}
```

I hope the code is self explanatory. cheers